# Replicating Hysteresis based Thresholding Technique to an Image from a Paper

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, thresholding

I was reading a [paper](https://www.intechopen.com/chapters/61732) where they applied a hysteresis thresholding to help with segmentation of vessels in an image. It provided a formula to determine how to select a hard threshold (Th), which represents pixels with a high probability of being blood vessel pixels and a weak threshold (Tw), which keeps all the pixels of the vascular tree in the surrounding region, even spurious ones. The values for Th and Tw are extracted from two characteristics calculated on the NIR images: the percentage of vascular tree and the percentage of background. These thresholds are calculated using percentile values, according to the below equation:

$$P_k = L_k + \frac{k(n / 100) - F_k}{f_k} \times c,\ k = 1, 2, \cdots, 99 .$$

Where $L_k$ is the percentile lower limit $k$, $n$ is the size of the data set, $F_k$ is the accumulated frequency for $k - 1$ values, $f_k$ depicts the frequency of percentile $k$ and $c$ is the measurement of the size of the percentile interval ($c = 1$). I am confused about what is meant by data set, does the above equation require all images?

The above was all that is mentioned and I am trying to understand how the percentile equation above will help me determine the hysteresis thresholds for one particular image.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to stack exchange.  When you cite a paper, web article, or book, could you please _cite it in your question_.  Those of us who answer questions are lazy, so including a link to something that's not behind a paywall, and/or quoting a few lines of the paper where you're getting confused will get you more attention.  Note that this is StackExchange, where you are encouraged to _edit your question_ with new information, and _strongly_ discouraged from burying it in comments.

Comment: LOL. “Open access, register to download”.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, While you need to register to download, but you can read the paper online without any registration.